# Excel VBA: Auto-sum the value of three cells and insert into the fourth cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have four columns A, B, C, D. The values of the cells start from A1,B1,C1,D1 and user may go up till A100,B100,C100,D100 (on click of a add button, after inserting values in each rows, one at a time)

When user will enter any value in A1 or B1 or C1, it should sum up and the value need to reflect in D1. There may be scenario like user may enter only values in one of the cell and leave other as it is. like A1 as blank, B1 as blank and C1 as 100. So in D1 it should reflect 100.

Just to mention, this is a protected sheet with a lot of different features, like cell level validation, sheet level validation, and the entire sheet will be locked other then one row where user will be able to enter the details and then he will click on ADD button, on click of this button, first all the fields will get validated and if successful then only a new row will be added.

Please help..

Comment: You need the SUM formula. No need for VBA.

Comment: Since its a protected sheet and nothing will work other than the VBA. As in VBA i need to first unprotect the cell, then use the formula and then protect it again. Sum formula is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't require any VBA code. Just enter following formula in `D1` cell: `=A1+B1+C1` and drag it all the way down until 100th row. This way, blank cells are treated as 0.

So, if cells in A,B,C columns are blank, correspnding value in D column will be 0.

Also, value in D column would be raclculated on every change in column A,B,C in corresponding row.

Comment: you can also add to format "D" such that if it is `0` it can appear blank. Perhaps not necessary but a nice visual touch.

Comment: Thanks Michal, your formula worked. i was using =sum(A1,B1,C1) and =sum(A1:C1)  that's why it was not working.